# Facebook Like popup disappears almost immediately

Tags: popup, facebook-like, overflow

I'm creating a blog on Blogger and I would like to include a Facebook Like button in the right column (width:280px). I'm using Blogger's HTML/JavaScript gadget. I got the HTML5 code which displays the button properly.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://myblogaddress.blogspot.com" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="60" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

When I click on it a popup shows up with option to add a comment but it disappears almost immediately. I figured out that this behavior is caused by overlapping with the < div > edge. I have tried to set various parameters which I thought might resolve the issue but it didn't work.

```
<div style="position:relative;overflow:auto;z-index:1;" class="fb-like" data-href="http://myblogaddress.blogspot.com" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="60" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

When I was searching for a solution I came across [this blog](http://www.simplebloggertutorials.com/2010/05/how-to-add-facebook-like-button-in.html) which also has the Facebook Like button in the right pane and it works like a charm, the popup window overlaps the edge and displays on top of everything else. Do you know how to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I realized it was a Chrome issue. IE and Firefox was working fine. Maybe check your Settings -> Advanced Settings > Privacy -> Content Settings -> Popups to ensure that Chrome doesn't prohibit the popup.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old post but I'll just leave an answer anyway :) I had the same issue and when trying to open the link in IE I get this error: "href+is+not+properly+formatted#" so I fixed my Url and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.
Turns out facebook closes the popup when there are mistakes in your opengraph declarations on the shared URL
in my case,
og:image lacked the domainname

cheers!